# predicting proportions in a sample with multiple dichotomous variables using a logit model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, prediction, proportion

For a (fictional) **multiple logistic regression**, let's consinder a DV 'hired' (0,1) and **three dichotomous IVs** 'college_degree' (0,1), 'affluent' (0,1) and 'recommendated' (0,1) for *N* = 1,000 participants.

Running a logistic regression and generating predicted probabilities of being hired using the `predict` function for a `glm` object works well. For every respondent I have a probability value ranging continuously from 0 to 1.

Since I do have a base distribution of all three IVs and the DV, I want a kind of simulator that predicts the **percentage/proportion** of the DV using each indivduals predicted probability.

Let's say in the sample 20% are hired, 50% have a college degree, 10% are affluent and 35% are recommendated. I want to use the predicted values to see how much would the **proportion of 'hired' goes** up, when I, e.g., **change the proportion of recommendations to 50%**. I guess, I could also use the equation with the coefficients of the logit model, but would need to run it for every individual.

Is there any way to implement this in R (well or Excel, if that is easier)?

Comment: Some notes: "multivariate" means multiple response variables, *multiple* LR means multiple IVs; to do what you want, just take the fitted regression equation & plug in the values that interest you, then transform the resulting ln odds to a proportion via exp(lo)/(1+ exp(lo)).

Comment: Thanks gung. Sure that I can fill in the proportion next to the logits? Like (for one IV, just as an example)  `y = 0.45 * 50% (or 0.5)`? Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Was the model fit to proportions? That doesn't seem likely. Typically, you have a rectangular dataset where each row is a person who was hired or not, w/ a degree or not, is or isn't affluent & was or wasn't recommended. The fitted model gives you coefficients for those variables & you can use those to calculate predicted %'s for whatever combinations of variables interests you. You may want to read through some of the threads categorized under the [tag:logistic] tag to become more familiar w/ how LR works.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it would make a big difference *which* 35% of people have a recommendation to start with (e.g. in terms of how many of them also have a degree) and also *which* 15% of people you switch from "not recommended" to "recommended" if you want to model a change to 50%. I suspect there's a statistical, rather than computational issue, in here which is on-topic. But you would need to clarify what assumptions you are making about your independent variables. (If all you want to know is "how can I code this in R", then that'd be off-topic here.)

Comment: Hi gung, yes, then I got you wrong ;) I know how the LR works, and it works just fine, and also yes, I have a dataset as you described (one line per respondent which each has a 0 or 1).What I want to do is without having to run the "filled-in-values"-equation for every single respondent, I thought of some way to "rescale" this to 50% of all the 1,000 respondents now have a 1 in "recommended" e.g.

Comment: @Silverfish - thanks, yes the distribution of, let's say those who would get a 1 instead of a 0 in "recommended" should be randomly assigned. Or would you rather assign the according to the relation of "degree" and "affluent" to "recommended"? But in the end I still have to specify values on a _person-level_  and the run the equation?

Comment: This is complicated by the fact we'd expect the independent variables to be correlated with each other in some way. You're effectively changing the makeup of the population you're regressing on, and I'm not sure how much sense it makes to do that in a way which is purely random. Just my 2 cents: if you had just two categorical (easiest with binary) predictors, then you could fill in a (with two binaries, 2x2) contingency table expressing the exact combination of characteristics you require. Once you get up to 3 variables, it's the same idea but more complicated.

Comment: alright, that was what I thought - I just hoped there was a (unknown to me) solution for extraploating this to a proportion of a sample level. Thanks for your help - much appreciated!°